# How can I loop through an XML file and parse tag content if each Sibling tag has different child tags?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

Is there a loop that will iterate through the siblings elements, if it gets to one of the studentscreening(see below) and that student does not have the tag being used, then input null/na ??

Below is what is in my xml file [studentinfo.xml]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentBreakdown>
<Studentdata>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Sam Davies</name>
        <age>15</age>
        <hair>Black</hair>
        <eyes>Blue</eyes>
        <grade>10</grade>
        <teacher>Draco Malfoy</teacher>
        <dorm>Innovation Hall</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Cassie Stone</name>
        <age>14</age>
        <hair>Science</hair>
        <grade>9</grade>
        <teacher>Luna Lovegood</teacher>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Derek Brandon</name>
        <age>17</age>
        <eyes>green</eyes>
        <teacher>Ron Weasley</teacher>
        <dorm>Hogtie Manor</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
</Studentdata>
</StudentBreakdown>
```

My code is iterating through the studentinfo.xml file and inputting the information into a `pandas` dataframe(df1) per the columns I've mapped the tags to.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('studentinfo.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()  

def parse_xml(file):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['StudentName', 'Age', 'Hair', 'Eyes', 'Grade', 'Teacher', 'Dorm'])
    all_items = soup.find_all('info')
    items_length = len(all_items)
    for index, info in enumerate(all_items):
        StudentName = info.find('<name>').text
        Age = info.find('<age>').text
        Hair = info.find('<hair>').text
        Eyes = info.find('<eyes>').text
        Grade = info.find('<grade>').text
        Teacher = info.find('<teacher>').text
        Dorm = info.find('<dorm>').text
      row = {
            'StudentName': StudentName,
            'Age': Age,
            'Hair': Hair,
            'Eyes': Eyes,
            'Grade': Grade,
            'Teacher': Teacher,
            'Dorm': Dorm
        }
        
        df1 = df1.append(row, ingore_index=True)
        print(f'Appending row %s of %s' %(index+1, items_length))
    
    return df1
```

When I try to run the code I get this error:
'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text''
Which my conclusion as to why I was getting this error was because not every StudentScreening has the same child tags being used.

What condition can be added to my code that says:
" As I am looping through, If an element tag is not present, input null in the dataframe and continue to enumerate over the file"
??????

Comment: Pandas' dedicated IO XML method, [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), will fill in optional tags. Introduced in v1.3, it's surprising pandas users still do not know this method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentBreakdown>
<Studentdata>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Sam Davies</name>
        <age>15</age>
        <hair>Black</hair>
        <eyes>Blue</eyes>
        <grade>10</grade>
        <teacher>Draco Malfoy</teacher>
        <dorm>Innovation Hall</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Cassie Stone</name>
        <age>14</age>
        <hair>Science</hair>
        <grade>9</grade>
        <teacher>Luna Lovegood</teacher>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Derek Brandon</name>
        <age>17</age>
        <eyes>green</eyes>
        <teacher>Ron Weasley</teacher>
        <dorm>Hogtie Manor</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
</Studentdata>
</StudentBreakdown>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "xml")

all_data = []
for s in soup.select("StudentScreening"):
    all_data.append(
        {
            "name": s.find("name"),
            "age": s.age,
            "eyes": s.eyes,
            "grade": s.grade,
            "teacher": s.teacher,
            "dorm": s.dorm,
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).apply(lambda x: [v.text if v else "N/A" for v in x])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            name age   eyes grade        teacher             dorm
0     Sam Davies  15   Blue    10   Draco Malfoy  Innovation Hall
1   Cassie Stone  14    N/A     9  Luna Lovegood              N/A
2  Derek Brandon  17  green   N/A    Ron Weasley     Hogtie Manor
```

Comment: Hey I tried this and it runs [sort of]. I am getting: Series([ ] , dtype: float64)                                             I did change the for loop up a bit to: for s in soup.select("enc\: StudentScreening"):

Comment: @Tej Try `soup.find_all('enc:StudentScreening')`

Comment: Hey I tried this and it runs [sort of]. I am getting: 'code' Series([ ] , dtype: float64)                                    ................     I did change the for loop up a bit to: for s in soup.select("enc\: StudentScreening"): .............. I included \ to escape the colon, if I didn't use it, it would have thrown back a psuedo-class error. How can I get my output like yours??

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't allow me to edit my comment lol.

Comment: I will try that. I am creating a separate question for namespaces now... as they're creating a little bit of a headache for me .

Answer (score 1):

While using `pandas` simply use its `pandas.read_xml()`:

```
pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//StudentScreening')
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd

xml = '''
<StudentBreakdown>
<Studentdata>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Sam Davies</name>
        <age>15</age>
        <hair>Black</hair>
        <eyes>Blue</eyes>
        <grade>10</grade>
        <teacher>Draco Malfoy</teacher>
        <dorm>Innovation Hall</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Cassie Stone</name>
        <age>14</age>
        <hair>Science</hair>
        <grade>9</grade>
        <teacher>Luna Lovegood</teacher>
    </StudentScreening>
    <StudentScreening>
        <name>Derek Brandon</name>
        <age>17</age>
        <eyes>green</eyes>
        <teacher>Ron Weasley</teacher>
        <dorm>Hogtie Manor</dorm>
    </StudentScreening>
</Studentdata>
</StudentBreakdown>'''

pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//StudentScreening')
```

##### Output

|  | name | age | hair | eyes | grade | teacher | dorm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sam Davies | 15 | Black | Blue | 10 | Draco Malfoy | Innovation Hall |
| 1 | Cassie Stone | 14 | Science |  | 9 | Luna Lovegood |  |
| 2 | Derek Brandon | 17 |  | green | nan | Ron Weasley | Hogtie Manor |

Comment: Question: Is there a way to use pandas.read_xml() with out a URI/URL for namespaces? 
In my original: StudentScreening has a namespace prefix: Stu:StudentScreening.

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and providing the specific XML example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376254/is-there-a-way-to-use-pandas-read-xml-with-out-a-uri-url-for-namespaces