# Is there a way to use pandas.read_xml() with out a URI/URL for namespaces?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

In my XML file [studentinfo.xml] some tags have namespace prefixes, is there a way to loop through the xml file and parse tag content [all sibling and child tags] without defining the URI/URL for namespace?

If you have another way of parsing the xml file not using pandas I am open to any and all solutions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stu:StudentBreakdown>
<stu:Studentdata>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Sam Davies</st:name>
        <st:age>15</st:age>
        <st:hair>Black</st:hair>
        <st:eyes>Blue</st:eyes>
        <st:grade>10</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Draco Malfoy</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Innovation Hall</st:dorm>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Cassie Stone</st:name>
        <st:age>14</st:age>
        <st:hair>Science</st:hair>
        <st:grade>9</st:grade>
        <st:teacher>Luna Lovegood</st:teacher>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
    <stu:StudentScreening>
        <st:name>Derek Brandon</st:name>
        <st:age>17</st:age>
        <st:eyes>green</st:eyes>
        <st:teacher>Ron Weasley</st:teacher>
        <st:dorm>Hogtie Manor</st:dorm>
    </stu:StudentScreening>
</stu:Studentdata>
</stu:StudentBreakdown>
```

below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('studentinfo.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()  

def parse_xml(file):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['StudentName', 'Age', 'Hair', 'Eyes', 'Grade', 'Teacher', 'Dorm'])
    all_items = soup.find_all('info')
    items_length = len(all_items)
    for index, info in enumerate(all_items):
        StudentName = info.find('<st:name>').text
        Age = info.find('<st:age>').text
        Hair = info.find('<st:hair>').text
        Eyes = info.find('<st:eyes>').text
        Grade = info.find('<st:grade>').text
        Teacher = info.find('<st:teacher>').text
        Dorm = info.find('<st:dorm>').text
      row = {
            'StudentName': StudentName,
            'Age': Age,
            'Hair': Hair,
            'Eyes': Eyes,
            'Grade': Grade,
            'Teacher': Teacher,
            'Dorm': Dorm
        }
        
        df1 = df1.append(row, ingore_index=True)
        print(f'Appending row %s of %s' %(index+1, items_length))
    
    return df1
```

Desired Output:

|  | Name | age | hair | eyes | grade | teacher | dorm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sam Davies | 15 | Black | Blue | 10 | Draco Malfoy | Innovation Hall |
| 1 | Cassie Stone | 14 | Science | N/A | 9 | Luna Lovegood | N/A |
| 2 | Derek Brandon | 17 | N/A | green | N/A | Ron Weasley | Hogtie Manor |

Comment: Whats the output you expect?

Comment: @Greg Hey I updated the question displaying the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were about **90% there**. I just fixed up a couple of things:

- `all_items` : to find `StudentScreening` instead of `info`
- `info.find()` statements : dealt with **missing values**
- `pd.concat()` : instead of `df1.append()`
- called the function parse_xml at the end

**Here is the code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read in the XML file
with open('studentinfo.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()  

def parse_xml(file):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['StudentName', 'Age', 'Hair', 'Eyes', 'Grade', 'Teacher', 'Dorm'])
    all_items = soup.find_all('StudentScreening')
    for index, info in enumerate(all_items):

        row = {
            'StudentName': info.find('name').text if info.find('name') else np.nan,
            'Age': info.find('age').text if info.find('age') else np.nan,
            'Hair': info.find('hair').text if info.find('hair') else np.nan, 
            'Eyes': info.find('eyes').text if info.find('eyes') else np.nan,
            'Grade': info.find('grade').text if info.find('grade') else np.nan,
            'Teacher': info.find('teacher').text if info.find('teacher') else np.nan,
            'Dorm': info.find('dorm').text if info.find('dorm') else np.nan
        }
        
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.Series(row).to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)
        
    
    return df1  


print(parse_xml(file))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     StudentName Age     Hair   Eyes Grade        Teacher             Dorm
0     Sam Davies  15    Black   Blue    10   Draco Malfoy  Innovation Hall
1   Cassie Stone  14  Science    NaN     9  Luna Lovegood              NaN
2  Derek Brandon  17      NaN  green   NaN    Ron Weasley     Hogtie Manor
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer using an `ElementTree`:

- Import the XML file
- Remove the namespace prefixes using `regex sub()` method
- Convert the XML document into an `ElementTree`
- Iterate through the relevant nodes to extract the information needed
- Convert to a dataframe with the expected output

**Here is the code:**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import pandas as pd

# import the file
with open('studentinfo.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()  
    
# remove namespace prefixes    
file = re.sub(r'stu?:', '', file)

# Extract the XML into an ElementTree
root = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(file)).getroot()

# translation between XML tags and column names
column_names = {'name': 'StudentName', 
                'age': 'Age', 
                'hair': 'Hair', 
                'eyes': 'Eyes', 
                'grade': 'Grade', 
                'teacher': 'Teacher', 
                'dorm': 'Dorm'}

# Extract the relevant information from the ElementTree
results = []
temp_dict = {}
for node in root.iter():
    if node.tag in column_names.keys():
        temp_dict[column_names[node.tag]] = node.text 
        
    elif len(temp_dict) > 0:
        results.append(temp_dict.copy())
        temp_dict.clear()

results.append(temp_dict.copy())    

# Create a dataframe from the extracted information
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     StudentName Age     Hair   Eyes Grade        Teacher             Dorm
0     Sam Davies  15    Black   Blue    10   Draco Malfoy  Innovation Hall
1   Cassie Stone  14  Science    NaN     9  Luna Lovegood              NaN
2  Derek Brandon  17      NaN  green   NaN    Ron Weasley     Hogtie Manor
```

---

And while you stipulated that you did not want to use pandas, I actually think it would be the easiest and cleanest method to implement.

Here is my answer using **pandas**:

```py
# import the file
with open('studentinfo.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read() 

# remove namespace prefixes    
file = re.sub(r'stu?:', '', file)

# read the xml file stipulating the node of interest
df = pd.read_xml(file, xpath="//StudentScreening")
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     StudentName Age     Hair   Eyes Grade        Teacher             Dorm
0     Sam Davies  15    Black   Blue    10   Draco Malfoy  Innovation Hall
1   Cassie Stone  14  Science    NaN     9  Luna Lovegood              NaN
2  Derek Brandon  17      NaN  green   NaN    Ron Weasley     Hogtie Manor
```

Comment: Hey @ScottC, I don't mind using pandas because it is generally the cleanest method. I just wasn't able to grab what I needed from pandas. I want it to iterate through the entire file [all parent, child, grandchild tags]. The file is pretty large and it has so many different tags, I shared a snippet with you all.

Comment: the beautiful soup answer you provided worked perfectly!